# What is IE9 compatibility view in IE9 Developer tools?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I am looking at IE 9 developer tools and when I click on browser mode I get a list

```
IE 7
IE 8
IE 9
IE 9 Compatibility View
```

What does that do? What is the difference between IE 9 and IE 9 Compatibility View ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *main* difference is the User-Agent string.  For Internet Explorer 9, the [new and improved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986085(v=vs.85).aspx) UA string is sent:

> `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)`

For compatibility view, something similar to the following string will be sent:

> `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Zune 4.7)`

Notice how the compatibility view UA string identifies the browser as **MSIE 7.0**?  Document mode isn't enough for compatibility view to work as intended.  The reason for this is you can't truly be backwards compatible if you still tell *the web server* you're running IE 9 — it may have some server side code that identifies IE 7 browsers and dishes out content specific to that browser.  Thus, the developer tools gives you the opportunity to see how your web page would look if a user clicked the "Compatibility View" icon, without switching compatibility view on permanently.

For the sake of completeness, it's also worth mentioning that the app version string changes in a similar way. IE 9's app version string is:

> `5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)`

And in compatibility view (may vary depending on software installed):

> `4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Zune 4.7)`

These strings are very similar to the UA string, but client-side scripts may refer to this string instead of the UA string.  IE 9 can still be identified in both the UA string and the app version string from the **`Trident/5.0`** part, regardless of compatibility mode.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, 9 Compatibility View is the features of MSIE 9 but with certain capabilities backed up to be compatible with MSIE 7. Also in principle, 7 is the same as MSIE 7, and 8 is the same as MSIE 8. But in fact, if you toggle to 7 and back to 9 Compatibility View, it behaves somewhat differently from just starting in 9 Compatibility View. Also, there are significant differences between 7 and the original MSIE 7.0.  Therefore, it is impossible to give a clear complete and accurate answer to your question.