# IE9 erroneously redirecting to mobile site

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

On our index page we have script to redirect users who are on smartphones (iPhone, Android & Windows Phone) to our mobile site. The technique we use is:

```
if ( navigator.userAgent.match( /iPhone/ ) && ! navigator.userAgent.match( /iPad/ ) ) {
        window.location="mobile.html";
        }
    else if ( navigator.userAgent.match( /Android/ ) && ! navigator.userAgent.match( /Android 3/) ) {
        window.location="mobile.html";
        }
    else if ( navigator.userAgent.match( /Windows Phone/ ) || navigator.userAgent.match( /Zune/ ) ) {
        window.location="mobile.html";
        }
```

Everything was working perfectly until we tested this on IE9 which for some reason redirects to the mobile site, even though its userAgent does not contain any of the strings above. The userAgent for IE9 is:

Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)

IE8 does not behave this way nor does any other platform. Is the script incorrect or did IE strike down again with its vengeful douchebaggery? Thanks.

Comment: If you debug through the code can you see which one it is falling into?

Comment: @RMX - I agree with Adam. Try issuing a `console.log(navigator.userAgent);` in each control structure to determine which condition is being matched and exactly what userAgent is being reported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [post regarding IE9 User Agents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465584/what-is-ie9-compatibility-view-in-ie9-developer-tools) is that IE9 changes its User Agent when in compatibility mode and can contain the 'Zune' string. Looks like we'll have to try and use another string to redirect Windows Phone users. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to. Just make sure you specify the correct doctype and IE9 won't go into compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the .match() method, it returns array, which can be empty(`[]`) or not.
IE is probrably considering that `[]` is a `true` expression, so I suggest you to do the following:

```
if(/iPhone/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !/iPad/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    window.location="mobile.html";
}else if(/Android/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !/Android 3/.test(navigator.userAgent){
    window.location="mobile.html";
}else if(/Windows Phone/.test(navigator.userAgent) || /Zune/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    window.location="mobile.html";
}
```

I guess it's gonna work because the .test() method will only return `true` or `false`

Comment: IE9 is still redirecting to the mobile site with your script. We removed the last line of the script (the one w/ 'Windows Phone' and 'Zune') and now IE9 does not redirect. Also made sure the userAgent in the IE9 Developers Tools was selected to Default and not changed to anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer and help.  The following worked for me using a Windows 8 Phone

```
if(/iPhone/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !/iPad/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    window.location="/mobile";
}else if(/Android/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !/Android 3/.test(navigator.userAgent){
    window.location="/mobile";
}else if(/Windows Phone/.test(navigator.userAgent) || /Zune/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    window.location="/mobile";
}
```

I changed the window.location="mobile.html" to the actual directory I created for the mobile's index.html file

```
ex. /root directory/mobile
```